# Append to Node to an Empty LinkedList in Rust, self.head.borrow_next() is None and not self.tail

Tags: unit-testing, rust, linked-list

I have tried to reimplement LinkedList in Rust, below are my codes:

```rust
#![allow(dead_code)]

use std::cell::{RefCell, Ref, RefMut};
use std::rc::Rc;

type WrappedNode<T> = Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>;

#[derive(Debug, PartialOrd, PartialEq, Clone)]
pub struct Node<T> where
  T: Clone 
  {
    next: Option<WrappedNode<T>>,
    data: T,
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialOrd, PartialEq)]
pub struct LinkedList<T> where
  T: Clone 
  {
    head: Option<WrappedNode<T>>,
    tail: Option<WrappedNode<T>>,
}

impl<T> Iterator for LinkedList<T> where
  T: Clone 
  {
type Item = WrappedNode<T>;
  
  fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
    unimplemented!()
  }
}

impl<T> Node<T> where
  T: Clone
  {
  pub fn new(data: T) -> Self {
    Self {
      next: None,
      data,
    }
  }

  pub fn borrow_data(self: &Self) -> &T {
    &self.data
  }

  pub fn borrow_next(self: &Self) -> Option<Ref<Node<T>>> {
    match &self.next {
      Some(next_exists) => {
        Some(next_exists.borrow())
      },
      None => {
        None
      }
    }
  }

  pub fn borrow_mut_next(self: &Self) -> Option<RefMut<Node<T>>> {
    match &self.next {
      Some(next_exists) => {
        Some(next_exists.borrow_mut())
      },
      None => {
        None
      }
    }
  }

  pub fn set_next(self: &mut Self, next: Node<T>) {
    let next_node = Rc::new(RefCell::new(next));
    self.next = Some(next_node);
  }
}

impl<T> LinkedList<T> where
  T: Clone
  {
  pub fn new_empty() -> Self {
    Self {
      head: None,
      tail: None,
    }
  }

  pub fn new_with_node(first_node: Node<T>) -> Self {
    let mut new_ll = Self::new_empty();
    Self::append(&mut new_ll, first_node);
    new_ll
  }

  pub fn append(&mut self, node: Node<T>) {
    assert!(node.next.is_none()); // make sure its not joining two linkedlists
    
    match self.tail.take() {
      Some(old_tail) => {
        old_tail
          .borrow_mut()
          .set_next(node.clone());
        },

      None => {
        let mut node_clone = node.clone();
        node_clone.next = self.tail.clone();
        self.head = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(node_clone)));
      }
    }
    self.tail = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(node)));
  }
  
}

// CRUD -> create new, add to head tail, read head tail, update anywhere, delete anywhere, delete head tail

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
  use super:: {Node, LinkedList};
  use std::rc::Rc;
  use std::cell::RefCell;
  
  #[test]
  fn test_node_ref_data() {
    let node = Node::new(5);
    assert_eq!(node.borrow_data(), &5);
  }

  #[test]
  fn test_node_ref_next() {
    let node = Node::new(5);
  assert!(node.borrow_next().is_none());
  }

  #[test]
  fn test_node_set_next() {
    let mut node = Node::new(33);
    let next_node = Node::new(34);
    Node::set_next(&mut node,
                   next_node);
    assert_eq!(node
               .borrow_next()
               .unwrap()
               .borrow_data(), &34);
  }

  #[test]
  fn test_ll_new_empty() {
    #[derive(Debug, PartialEq, PartialOrd, Clone)]
    struct NTH;
    let new_ll = LinkedList::<NTH>::new_empty();
    assert_eq!(new_ll, LinkedList{head: None, tail: None})
  }

  #[test]
  fn test_ll_new_with_node() {
    let new_node = Node::new(45);
    let new_node_two = new_node.clone();
    let new_node_three = new_node.clone();
    let new_ll = LinkedList::new_with_node(new_node);
    let new_node_two = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(new_node_two)));
    let new_node_three = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(new_node_three)));
    
    assert_eq!(new_ll, LinkedList{head: new_node_two, tail: new_node_three})
  }

  #[test]
  fn test_ll_new_with_node_head_borrow_next_is_tail() {
    let new_node = Node::new(45);
    let new_node_two = new_node.clone();
    let new_ll = LinkedList::new_with_node(new_node);
    let new_node_two = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(new_node_two)));
    assert_eq!(new_ll
            .head
            .unwrap()
            .borrow()
            .borrow_next()
            .unwrap()
            .borrow_data(), new_node_two.unwrap().borrow().borrow_data());
  }

  #[test]
  fn test_ll_append_tail() {
    let new_node = Node::new(45);
    let new_node_two = new_node.clone();
    let mut new_ll = LinkedList::new_with_node(new_node);
    let new_node_two = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(new_node_two)));

    let append_node = Node::new(77);
    LinkedList::append(&mut new_ll, append_node);
    assert_eq!(new_ll
              .tail
              .unwrap()
              .borrow()
              .borrow_data(), &77)
  }

  #[test]
  fn test_ll_append_first_borrow_next() {
    let new_node = Node::new(45);
    let new_node_two = new_node.clone();
    let mut new_ll = LinkedList::new_with_node(new_node);
    let new_node_two = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(new_node_two)));

    let append_node = Node::new(77);
    LinkedList::append(&mut new_ll, append_node);
    assert_eq!(new_ll
              .head
              .unwrap()
              .borrow()
              .borrow_next()
              .unwrap()
              .borrow_data(), &77)
  }

// end of tests
}
```

Two tests failed, as shown below:

```
running 8 tests
test same_type_linked_list::tests::test_ll_new_empty ... ok
test same_type_linked_list::tests::test_ll_append_tail ... ok
test same_type_linked_list::tests::test_ll_new_with_node_head_borrow_next_is_tail ... FAILED
test same_type_linked_list::tests::test_ll_append_first_borrow_next ... FAILED
test same_type_linked_list::tests::test_ll_new_with_node ... ok
test same_type_linked_list::tests::test_node_ref_data ... ok
test same_type_linked_list::tests::test_node_set_next ... ok
test same_type_linked_list::tests::test_node_ref_next ... ok

failures:

---- same_type_linked_list::tests::test_ll_new_with_node_head_borrow_next_is_tail stdout ----
thread 'same_type_linked_list::tests::test_ll_new_with_node_head_borrow_next_is_tail' panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value', src/same_type_linked_list.rs:176:14

---- same_type_linked_list::tests::test_ll_append_first_borrow_next stdout ----
thread 'same_type_linked_list::tests::test_ll_append_first_borrow_next' panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value', src/same_type_linked_list.rs:210:16
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace


failures:
    same_type_linked_list::tests::test_ll_append_first_borrow_next
    same_type_linked_list::tests::test_ll_new_with_node_head_borrow_next_is_tail
```

I suspect during the appending of a new `Node<T>`, concretely `Node<u64>`, to an empty `LinkedList` the `self.head.next` is not pointing to `self.tail`, despite me setting it explicitly. The error occurs when I call `unwrap()` on the `None` value which is returned from `borrow_next()`, an associated method of `Node<T>` to return a reference of the field `.next`. That means that `new_ll.head.borrow_next()` which ideally should return a reference to `new_ll.tail` instead returns a `None`, meaning that it is not pointing to new_ll.tail when a first node is appended/inserted into a completely empty `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code the head node is the one that you give to in

```
LinkedList::new_with_node()
```

Its calling

```
 pub fn new_empty() -> Self {
    Self {
      head: None,
      tail: None,
    }
```

i.e. its initialized with no head node. So when you construct your list with a node you are adding a head

```
  pub fn new_with_node(first_node: Node<T>) -> Self {
    let mut new_ll = Self::new_empty();
    Self::append(&mut new_ll, first_node);
    new_ll
  }

  pub fn append(&mut self, node: Node<T>) {
    assert!(node.next.is_none()); // make sure its not joining two linkedlists
    
    match self.tail.take() {
      Some(old_tail) => {
        old_tail
          .borrow_mut()
          .set_next(node.clone());
        },

      None => {
        let mut node_clone = node.clone();
        node_clone.next = self.tail.clone();
        self.head = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(node_clone)));
      }
    }
```

You are also calling append by explicitly passing the newly created list as self.

```
Self::append(&mut new_ll, first_node);
```

You could have called it

```
   new_ll.append(first_node)
```

You are assuming there is another node beyond the head in your test:

```
assert_eq!(new_ll
              .head
              .unwrap()
              .borrow()
              .borrow_next()
              .unwrap()
              .borrow_data(), &77)
```